Brazil Transit Visa for Indian Passport holder
I was Booked on British Airways flight originating from Mumbai via LHR then next flight from LHR to Sao Paulo and then next flight from Sao Paulo to Santiago.  Both arrival from LHR by BA and then departure to Santiago through LATAM were from Guarulhos, Terminal 3.
British Airways did not allow me and my family to board the flight from Mumbai citing that we did not have a Brazil transit visa.
According to Brazilian Embassy in New Delhi this is not required as we are Indian passport holders not entering into Brazil but transiting through Brazil ( 1.5 hours was transit time) as flight to Santiago within 1.5 hours.
Sharing the link of Brazilian embassy sent to me:https://www.gov.br/mre/pt-br/embaixada-nova-delhi/embassy-of-brazil-in-new-delhi/visas/transit-visa-vivis

If you have one single ticket, under a single booking reference,
stating both the origin and the final destination, regardless of
multiple stopovers or multiple carriers, and as long as you remain in
the transit zone, you do not require a transit visa. If you have
separate tickets for inbound and outbound flights, a transit visa is
required

My question is : was British Airways right in not allowing us to board the flight? We even though booked on a Business Class were not allowed to fly by BA.
NEED YOUR HELP AND Guidance

At what airport was your LHR > Sao Paulo flight to arrive? From what airport was your Sao Paulo > Santiago flight to depart?

@DavidRecallsMonica While that is important for the visa question, I severely doubt that the OP would be changing airports with a 1.5 Hr layover.  It's at least a 30 minute drive from Guarulhos to the next closest airport.  And that's just the drive, and doesn't include passing through immigration and security etc.

Both arrival from LHR by BA and then departure to Santiago thru LATAM was from SAO PAULO, SP (GUARULHOS INTL), TERMINAL 3

Was the entire trip Mumbai>LHR>Sao Paolo>Santiago booked as a single ticket (ie one PNR) via BA?

I deleted my answer cause after re-reading this I understand that a visa is still not required: https://www.gov.br/mj/pt-br/assuntos/noticias/brasil-vira-rota-de-contrabando-de-migrantes-e-mjsp-muda-regras-para-a-entrada-no-pais

I’m voting to close this question because clarity is needed on whether the LATAM flight segment was booked as a self-transfer. AFAIK BA flights from LHR to Santiago, Chile seem to be either direct or via Madrid (Iberia, not LATAM).
